# R: "For Loop" is Creating a Single File Instead of Two Files

Tags: r, for-loop

I am using the R programming language. I have a "data frame" called "a" that has 2 rows and 1 column (the column is called "file.list"):

```
>head(a)
                                               file.list
1 C:/Users/Documents/files_i_want/1_a.pdf
2 C:/Users/Documents/files_i_want/a_1.pdf
```

I am trying to write a "for loop" that performs an operation using each "element" from this data frame:

```
library(tesseract)
library(pdftools)

for (i in 1:2)
 { 

file_i = tesseract::ocr(a[i, "file.list"]) 

}
```

The above code successfully runs:

```
Converting page 1 to 1_a_1.png... done!
Converting page 1 to a_1_1.png... done!
```

**Problem:** The above loop is only creating a single file instead of two files. Does anyone know why this is happening? Can someone please show me how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are overwriting the same file (`file_i`) in the loop.

Ideally you should use list to save them.

```
file <- vector('list', 2)

for (i in 1:2){ 
  file[[i]] = tesseract::ocr(a[i, "file.list"]) 
}
```

If you want to save them as different objects like `file_1`, `file_2` in global environment, use `assign` -

```
for (i in 1:2){ 
  assign(paste0('file_', i), tesseract::ocr(a[i, "file.list"])) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do this in `lapply`

```
files <- lapply(a$file.list, function(x) tesseract::ocr(x))
names(files) <- paste0('file_', seq_along(files))
```

If it needs to be assigned as objects, use `list2env`

```
list2env(files, .GlobalEnv)
```